# Drawing/Manipulating a polygon in QT C++

Tags: c++, qt

I am currently new to QT C++, and I was wondering, how would I go around allowing the user to draw a polygon with maximum of 10 vertices (x1,y1 up to x10,y10)? I know there are probably inbuilt functions to aid with that in the QT library.

Also, in the event the user successfully manages to draw their desired shape, what approach would I need to use to further allow the user to draw out the shape's vertices to enlarge the image or simply change its shape by dragging a particular angle.

I am looking forward to hearing from you soon!

Comment: If you want to draw something in Qt, then you must use the QPainter class. There is a detailed example project here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-painting-basicdrawing-example.html
Changing the shape by dragging a point or angle is much more complex.

Comment: I'll definitely have a look at that. Cheers

Comment: @Liachei there have example for that too, but in that case a QGraphicsView is used which is a OOP-based environment to manage visual components. It has a lot of functionality fit for vector editors or diagram editors like MS Visio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elastic Nodes Example and Diagram Scene Example from Qt library exemplify usage of component called QGraphicsView. It's not direct drawing but creating scene of preset components. You would create own components of classes which would implement actual drawing as well as certain behavior, e.g. reacting to user actions, colliding, animation, etc. You easily can start to make your own vector or diagram editor with those.

For direct render to raster image or widget surface QPainter and QImage are used.